# How can I automate UI testing in Chrome, Microsoft Edge, or any other browser?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, google-chrome, cross-browser, microsoft-edge

I need to test a large number of websites in Chrome, Microsoft Edge, et al. The primary thing I need to do is some automation such as:

1. Login
2. Ensure popups are functional (JavaScript checks this)
3. Fill out a form
4. Click a button
5. Wait
6. Click a JS button
7. Fill out a form
8. Click a JS button
9. Repeat, but this time with different data.

Since I'm testing 100 different scenarios, I expect 1 through 8 to be repeated, but with very specific data.

How do I go about testing Chrome, IE, or any other browser in this way?

Answer (score 3):

Yep! You are looking for Selenium/WebDriver. If you want to write the tests in javascript, [wd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wd) is one of the most popular node clients (there are webdriver bindings for most popular languages).